# Eclipse: How to disable '!=' token replacement

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm currently using Eclipse 2019-09 for Java Programming, and I've noticed that when I type the operator '!=', the IDE replaces it with "not-equals" symbol, ≠.

I do not like this.

I don't think this is from any plugins I have installed. Is this standard behaviour and is it possible to disable the operator token replacement within Eclipse?

Comment: I am not able to simulate.

Comment: You're using a font with ligatures. Use another font, or disable the ligatures. I don't know where to do that because I don't use Eclipse, but the "font" and "ligature" keywords should enable you to find this in the configuration.

Comment: Who *wants* "features" like this? It seems like the sort of thing somebody thought would be "cool", but more likely just causes cognitive load.

Comment: @AndyTurner I for one couldn't live *without* ligatures, so I guess it depends on what your brain is used to.  
A (well-designed) ligatures font *reduces* cognitive load: it saves you the steps of combining two glyps `!=` into one mental `is-not`, and aids the eye in logical grouping.  I suggest having a look at the font design decisions going into, for example "[Jetbrains Mono](https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/mono/)".

Answer (score 1):

And the correct answer goes to [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet). My programming font is "Fantasque Sans Mono", and the latest version has just introduced ligatures, causing the token replacement.

Comment: Could you accept their answer instead and make this a comment, please?

Comment: JB Nizets answer is in the comments and thus not eligible to be an answer.

Comment: Sorry to bother you!

Answer (score 0):

This is a "feature" (requested back in 2013) See [bug 398656](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=398656) and I agree this is very distracting "like 'fi' now takes just one space in some fonts. Next thing, folks will request to code using MS Word or Latex.

The solution is to use a font that still does not have ligatures. Like Liberation Mono Regular and to select it in `Basic` => `Text Font` `General` `Appearance` preference as shown below. As far as I know there is no way to opt-out of that feature.

[image: Preference location]